# Search for pages with permalink

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I'm searching for posts this way

```
$args = array(
   'name' => $permalink,
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

This works great for "page1" and "foo/page2" when I put "page1" and "page2" respectively in `$permalink`.

How can I craft a query to work for the case with where I want to search for "foo/page2"?

**edit** i want to get the post object so that I can retrieve some data from it.

Comment: You want to search for a post name on a particular page of the paginated results?

Comment: @s_ha_dum not exactly. i just need to get a reference to the post object for it.

Comment: I don't know what "get a reference to the post object" means in this context. What is the significance of the page component? Please try to make the question more cleat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well (and I'm not sure) probably you need only the `get_page_by_path` function:

```
$pagefoo = get_page_by_path('foo/page2');
```

`$pagefoo` variable contain post object for the page with slug `'page2'` that is child of page with slug `'foo'`.